# Tiling large numbers of images onto sphere

Tags: uv

I want to be able to tile a large number of images onto a sphere to create an effect like the posters where each pixel is a small image of the appropriate colour. 
I'm thinking the way to do this would be to define a point on the sphere where each tile is centred so that if any given tile is viewed directly it will look nearly normal and have blender distort each tile as appropriate for the viewing angle.

Is there any way of doing this?

Ideally I'd like to keep the tiles as separate images so they can be easily exchanged. but if there is a simple script/ app to automatically merge them that would be fine

I thought someone might have done it with the planet tiles created by the space agencies, but I can't find anything.